# How can i flutter firestore cyclic query

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to make a query, if it conforms to a condition, I want to bring the query as the next query. Anybody have any idea how I can do it?

My goal is to do this on the client as there is no not-in-array query

```
Query _query(List<dynamic> startAfter) {
    CollectionReference col = _firestore.collection("users");
    Query xx= col.where('xx', whereIn: _xx);
    Query yy = xx.where('yy', arrayContains: _yy);
    Query zz = yy.orderBy('zz');
    Query start;
    if (startAfter.length > 0) {
      start = zz.startAfter(startAfter);
    } else {
      start = zz;
    }
    Query limit = start.limit(1);
    return limit;
  }
```

I thought something like this but I guess I couldn't do it right

```
_query([]).getDocuments().then((onValue) {
            if (onValue.documents.length > 0) {
              if (_all.contains(onValue.documents.first.documentID)) {
                List<DocumentSnapshot> doc = onValue.documents;
                String id = doc.first.documentID;
                do {
                  _query(doc).getDocuments().then((onValue) {
                    doc = onValue.documents;
                    id = doc.first.documentID;
                  });
                }
                while(_all.contains(id) == false);
                if(doc.length > 0) {
                  debugPrint('found');
                } else {
                  debugPrint('could not find');
                }
              } else {
                debugPrint('found');
              }
            } else {
              debugPrint('could not find');
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like that with await

```
Future<QuerySnapshot> _query([DocumentSnapshot startAfter]) {
    CollectionReference col = _firestore.collection("users");
    Query xx= col.where('xx', whereIn: _xx);
    Query yy = xx.where('yy', arrayContains: _yy);
    Query zz = yy.orderBy('zz');
    Query start;
    if (startAfter != null) {
      start = order.startAfterDocument(startAfter);
    } else {
      start = order;
    }
    Query limit = start.limit(1);
    return limit.getDocuments();
  }
```

after:

```
  QuerySnapshot snap = await _query();
  if (snap.documents.length > 0) {
    if (_all.contains(onValue.documents.first.documentID)) {
      List<DocumentSnapshot> doc = snap.documents;
      while (doc.length > 0 && _all.contains(doc.first.documentID) == false) {
        QuerySnapshot snap2 = await _query(doc.first);
        doc = snap2.documents;
      }
      if (doc.length > 0) {
        debugPrint('found');
      } else {
        debugPrint('could not find');
      }
    } else {
      debugPrint('found');
    }
  } else {
    debugPrint('could not find');
  }
```